# Infinite loop in react context caused by a setState inside a useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm getting infinite looping from this context component as soon as I enable the commented out line. I already completely isolated the component and still the problem is not solved.

This behavior only occurs when the row is discounted and the browser has the token in its cookies.

The code inside useEffect doesn't repeat infinitely, just the code at the top level.

Auth

```
'use client'

import { AxiosError } from 'axios'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { destroyCookie, parseCookies, setCookie } from 'nookies'
import {
    ReactNode,
    createContext,
    useCallback,
    useEffect,
    useMemo,
    useState
} from 'react'

import { Either, left, right } from '@core/logic/Either'
import { accessLevel, controllers, endpoints } from '@routes/backend'
import { Api } from '@services/api/Axios'
import { fetchLogin } from '@services/api/FetchLogIn'

export type TSystemUser = {
    name: string
    role: string
} | null

export type TLoginParams = {
    phoneNumber: string
    password: string
}

export type TLoginResponse = Either<unknown, unknown>

type TAuthContext = {
    systemUser: TSystemUser
    login: (data: TLoginParams) => Promise<Either<unknown, unknown>>
    logout: () => void
}

export const AuthContext = createContext({} as TAuthContext)

export async function AuthProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
    const [systemUser, setSystemUser] = useState<TSystemUser>(null)
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState<string | null>(null)
    const { 'nextauth-token': token } = parseCookies()

    if ((!accessToken && token) || accessToken !== token) {
        setAccessToken(token)
        Api.defaults.headers.authorization = token
    }

    if (accessToken && !token) {
        destroyCookie(undefined, 'nextauth-token')
        Api.defaults.headers.authorization = null
    }

    console.log('a') // 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' ...

    const fecthSystemUserInfo = useCallback(async (): Promise<
        Either<AxiosError<TSystemUser>, TSystemUser>
    > => {
        try {
            const response = await Api.get<TSystemUser>(
                accessLevel.session +
                    controllers.withSession +
                    endpoints.RetrieveUserInformation
            )

            return right(response.data)
        } catch (err) {
            const error = err as AxiosError<TSystemUser>

            switch (error.status) {
                default:
                    return left(error)
            }
        }
    }, [accessToken])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function retrieveUserInformation(): Promise<void> {
            const response = await fecthSystemUserInfo()

            if (response.isRight()) {
                const user = response.value

                console.log(user) // { name: 'User', role: 'Admin' }

                // await setSystemUser(user) // commented line
                console.log(systemUser) // null
            }

            console.log(response.value)
        }

        if (!systemUser && accessToken) {
            retrieveUserInformation()
        }

        if (systemUser && !accessToken) {
            setSystemUser(null)
        }

        console.log(systemUser)
    }, [accessToken])

    const login = useCallback(
        async ({
            phoneNumber,
            password
        }: TLoginParams): Promise<TLoginResponse> => {
            try {
                if (systemUser) {
                    return right(null)
                }

                const response = await fetchLogin({ phoneNumber, password })

                if (response.isLeft()) {
                    return left(response.value)
                }

                const { accessToken, user } = response.value

                setSystemUser(user)

                setCookie(undefined, 'nextauth-token', accessToken.token, {
                    expires: new Date(accessToken.expiresIn)
                })

                return right(null)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)

                return left(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2))
            }
        },
        [accessToken]
    )

    const logout = useCallback((): void => {
        const router = useRouter()

        destroyCookie(null, 'nextauth-token')
        Api.defaults.headers.authorization = null
        setSystemUser(null)

        router.push('/')
    }, [accessToken])

    const contextValue = useMemo(
        () => ({ systemUser, login, logout }),
        [accessToken]
    )

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

RootLayout

```
import '@styles/Globals/Globals.css'

import { ReactNode } from 'react'

import Footer from '@components/Footer/Footer'
import Header from '@components/Header/Header'
import { AuthProvider } from '@contexts/Auth/Auth'
import styles from '@styles/Components/MainLayout.module.css'

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <html lang="pt-br">
                <body>
                    <div className={styles.app}>
                        <Header />
                        {children}
                        <Footer />
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
        </AuthProvider>
    )
}
```

I expected the function inside useEffect to update the user (and it does), however this causes an infinite loop. Another behavior I would expect is that components using this context would be updated, and this is not the case.

Comment: Side note... `await setSystemUser(user)` - The `await` here won't do anything useful because state setters don't return a `Promise`.  Just remove the `await`.

Comment: I know that await has no effect, I've done the tests even without await and it has the same behavior.

Comment: You should never be updating state from the render method to begin with. Just get rid of that code smell instead of trying to work around it.

Comment: @Prinsqty: If that `useEffect` is being triggered over and over then that implies that `accessToken` is being updated over and over.  It appears to be conditionally updated on every render.  When you debug, is it that `if` block indeed being executed on every render and updating `accessToken` every time?  It sounds like that `if` block should itself be a `useEffect` as well, as updating state (even conditionally) directly in the component render is a direct cause of infinite re-renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if ((!accessToken && token) || accessToken !== token) {
   setAccessToken(token)
   Api.defaults.headers.authorization = token
}
```

this code will run at every component render and it is updating the access token state (`setAccessToken(token)`) so when the component rerenders `useEffect` will run since `accessToken` is included in its dependency array then `useEffect` is updating `systemUser` (`setSystemUser(user)`) so this will rerender the component again, **since the new value of `systemUser` is different of the old one**, you may think it is the same but two objects are always not equal, and when the component rerenders, **again**, the same will happen.

when you comment `setSystemUser(user)` then when `useEffect` runs it will not trigger a rerender because it does not update any state so you don't run into an infinite rerender

---

to handle this you don't want to set the access token in the body of your component but inside a `useEffect` that runs when the component first mounts:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (token) {
    setAccessToken(token);
    Api.defaults.headers.authorization = token;
  }
}, []);
```

now you can uncomment the line without getting an infinite render.